# NullPointerException from within String is confusing

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I've come across an exception that doesn't halt my program and really doesn't *seem* to cause any issues, but I'd like to know what causes it.

Here, I assign `SText.Text` to `"" + R;` R is an int constantly being added to `getWheelState()` below:

```
    SText ST = new SText("",Mainfont,Color.orange,10,300);
        Window.addEntity(ST);//Adds ST to a list of things to draw.
        int R = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            int C = SIn.getWheelState(); //static method that calls (Some MouseWheelEvent).getWheelRotation()
            ST.Text = ""+R; //Changing Text here
            if(R+C != R)
            {
                R += C;
            }
        }
```

R's value, which I assume *should* be irrelevent, if helpful, is the total mouse wheel scroll ticks. Positive towards you, negative away from you:

```
public class SInput extends MouseAdapter implements MouseListener, MouseWheelListener, KeyListener
{
    protected int MouseScrolled = 0;

    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e)
    {
        MouseScrolled += e.getWheelRotation();
    }
    public int HandleWheel()
    {
        int temp = MouseScrolled;
        MouseScrolled = 0;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Anyways, here is the method I've traced it to so far:

```
public class SText extends SEntity
{
    public String Text; public Color Col; public Font Fnt;
    public SText(String text,Font f,Color cl,int a,int b)
    {
        Fnt = f;
        Text = text;
        Col = cl;
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
            try
            {
                g.drawString(Text,x,y); // Line in question
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e)
            {
                if(Text != null && g != null)
                    throw e; //Exception gets thrown anyways
            }
    }

}
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.String.length(String.java:623)
at sun.font.GlyphList.setFromString(GlyphList.java:241)
at sun.java2d.pipe.GlyphListPipe.drawString(GlyphListPipe.java:71)
at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawString(SunGraphics2D.java:2829)
at SebsGameEngine.SText.draw(SText.java:29)
at SebsGameEngine.SPanel.paintComponent(SPanel.java:37)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:585)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5228)
at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1236)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1040)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:78)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:115)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1967)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3877)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:807)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:784)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:784)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:757)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:706)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(RepaintManager.java:62)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1647)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

If it helps at all, it only seems to happen when I deal with mouse wheel input.

But it still confuses me. What else *could* be `null` if not `g` or `Text`?

Comment: You are catching the exception and throwing a new one, loosing the original stack trace. Better change that to `throw e;`

Comment: You should not catch `NullPointerException`, this is a bad practice and there is no reason in your case.

Comment: What are the datatypes of `x` and `y`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks, leonbloy, I'll update the stack trace

Comment: It looks like the `String` `Text` that you are trying to draw is `null` . Would be much better if you show your more code.

Comment: if Text was null, it wouldn't re-throw the exception...

Comment: @VishalK It's not a `String` that is null. The NPE is within `String.length`.

Comment: @LaurentG I'm aware of this, it is just temporary until I can find the problem

Comment: That's an odd exception - it's from within `String.length`. Going to be JVM version dependent. Presumably unpacking from a byte array representation. I suggest getting the latest version of your JRE.

Comment: Actually I guess a `String` implementation that uses a full `char[]` without offset and length fields. Latest versions do that. Where did you get `Text` from?

Comment: Text is public and can be changed at anytime from outside the package. Not sure if it would make a difference, but it might.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: But `String.length` source code is   `public int length() {
   return count;
 }` . How NPE is possible within this method as`count` is a primitive?.

Comment: When you encounter high weirdness, set traps for it.  Try forcing Text to something sane and seeing if the NPE goes away.  Try logging Text.  Try logging every other access to Text to see if you have a race condition.

Comment: @VishalK It varies between versions. Version in front of me is `return value.length;`. / What appears to be important is how the instance of `String` assigned to `Text` was constructed.

Comment: My guess is that the String in question was created using the package-private constructor `String(char[], boolean)`.  That's the only way I've found to get `null` into the field `value`.  I'm using JDK 1.7.0_25 and I get the same line number in `String.length`.   However, I cannot say how this constructor was called.  If you can attach the JDK source and perhaps drop a breakpoint in this constructor, it would be interesting to see where it gets called from.

Comment: The string gets created and modified as such: `GUIEl.Text = ""+R;` (R is an `int`)

Answer (score 0):

To discover why Text is null you should show us the code segment where you instantiated SText class, because you initialize SText using text and text value set in the code segment where you make object from SText class. Please put your code here. Surely Text or g is null, because we have at SebsGameEngine.SText.draw(SText.java:29) and it shows in draw method null pointer exist.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that to my question.

Comment: Ok. Now I'm sure that g is null. Please tell me how you initialize g.

Comment: Dear Sebastian, please tell me why did you use if in the catch block? What's its benefit? If Text!= null and g!=null, then the exception is never thrown.

Comment: That's what confuses me: It _does_ get thrown.

Comment: I get `g` from overriding `paintComponent(Graphics g)` in `Jpanel`, from which I call `draw(g)` for every `Entity` that gets added. I simply add Spanel to a Jframe and let it take care of g.