# NullPointerException at java.lang.String.length(String.java:611)

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception

I'm completely riddled with the following stacktrace... Looks like it is caused by the `String` instance which has `null` char array internally. Putting aside reflection, is there any "legal" way to get such `String` instance in java?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.lang.String.length(String.java:611) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isEmpty(StringUtils.java:195) ~[commons-lang-2.6.jar:2.6]
```

Comment: Byte code manipulation or `Unsafe`, but no.

Answer (score 1):

If by *legal* you mean by using the constructors and methods exposed by the `String` API, then, no, it is not possible to reproduce such an exception.

There are ways to instantiate classes that will skip constructors and initializers. `sun.misc.Unsafe` provides such a utility, [`allocateInstance`](http://mishadoff.com/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String string = (String) getUnsafe().allocateInstance(String.class);
    System.out.println(string.length());
}

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
private static Unsafe getUnsafe() {
    try {
        Field singleoneInstanceField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        singleoneInstanceField.setAccessible(true);
        return (Unsafe) singleoneInstanceField.get(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

In this case, the `value` field of `String` will remain `null` and the `NullPointerException` will occur when invoking `length()`.

Similarly, some proxying libraries that use byte code manipulation can omit an invocation to `super()` when creating proxy subclasses, effectively skipping initialization. [Here's a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329966/failed-to-mock-arraylist-with-option-calls-real-methods) where mocking failed to properly initialize an `ArrayList`'s backing array.

Comment: Do you have any information, if Unsafe will still be available in Java 9?

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach Yeah, parts of it should be replaced with a new API that's part of the standard library. See [here](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/260).

Answer (score 0):

Also see for reports of an npe on the same line in String.
 - [NullPointerException from within String is confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495396/nullpointerexception-from-within-string-is-confusing)
 - [java Strings odd behavior with collator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993480/java-strings-odd-behavior-with-collator)
 - https://twitter.com/s1m0nw/status/829728992907448326

There's a `String(char[] value, boolean shared)` package protected constructor that does not do a null check.

My guess that this is used in combination with String intern, so not called directly by your code.

One hypothetical scenario here could be multithreading in combination with String intern. The value field in String is final but not volatile. This may lead to weird issues early in it's lifecycle.